# How can I reference data from MariaDB on web browser JS application?

Tags: javascript, database, mariadb

I am trying to create a web page that uses data from a MariaDB. My current idea (which has been giving me a lot of trouble) is to just connect to the database from the app.js file, which is the main script for my index.html.

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const mariadb = require("mariadb");
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  host: process.env.HOST,
  user: process.env.USER_TOKEN,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
});

// the rest of the code involves selecting from the db, and parsing the data
```

However, I have been running into many issues. I'm not too knowledgeable on all this, but I found that I need to webpack the file if I want to be able to use the "require" keyword. But I could not figure that out as I kept running into weird issues when using Browserify; I think there may be an incompatibility with MariaDB. I also looked into using JS modules, but I am not sure if that is possible with MariaDB.

I am trying to come up with another solution, potentially using some sort of API to a back end, which would make the GET request to the database, but I feel like it should not have to be that complicated for my sake (I also wouldn't really know where to start with this). All I basically want to do, is make a GET request to a MariaDB when the page loads on the client's browser and display that data on the web page. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use nodejs to connect and query database as it will greatly resolve a lot of overhead for you..

The easiest way i can think of is using a prisma starter template here

https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/javascript/script

It also gives the added advantage of the ORM function...

Hope it helps.